# Install old iPhone OS on development device

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to roll back an iPod Touch 2nd gen from the 3.0 OS to the 2.2.1 release so I can test my application on there. The documentation lists the OSes as being available on the dev center, but I'm unable to find them but for the 3.1 beta's. Did Apple just hide them where I didn't look, or are those files not available anymore, and if so, is there an alternative to rolling back the device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found a site that is an [interface to Apple's update feed](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/), listing all the available firmwares for both the IPod touch and the IPhone. Using the XCode Organizer it is then possible to load new firmwares unto the development device, however, to downgrade it is necessary to [put the device into DFU mode](http://osxmobile.nl/?p=226&cpage=1)

Comment: Your DFU mode link doesn't work anymore. This one does: http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=1034

Answer (score 2):

Same question over here:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9655781

Basically you have to find the 2.2.1 software yourself. That's why I always keep my copies of firmwares.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that rolling back to older releases is not officially supported.

Perhaps because of this, downgrading is not a simple point-and-click exercise. [I found a guide here](http://thebigboss.org/2009/03/19/iphone-v30-beta-do-not-use/). Most of the complexity is around the iPhone baseband firmware which shouldn't be a problem with the iPod touch.

Answer (score 0):

If you Google around you can usually find these.

Apple tries to hide them because they are paid updates (grr).

For iPhone users: http://www.poorlad.com/iCommunity/